# Change view in web view android

Tags: android, android-webview

Here is my [Code](http://pastie.org/8977847). I want to switch between 2 views **Mobile view & Desktop View**. Manually i set URL it's work but when i get URL using **webView.getOriginalUrl()** & load again then not work. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Please be clear what you mean by not working.

Comment: Here, 2 button. normally web view display mobile view but i want to web view display desktop view also. manually i load the url it's work perfect but using webView.getOriginalUrl() this method i got the url & & run again but that time view not change. disply only mobile view. not show desktop view. @ksasq

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the user agent of the second (desktop) WebView to be something that identifies it as a desktop browser[1].

It could also be that the site you are trying to load has set a cookie or some other piece of state that means it remembers that your app should be served the mobile version of the page.

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString(java.lang.String)